# How to subclass UIViewController with multiple nibs / xibs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to subclass UIViewController with multiple nibs.

For example:

BaseViewController has a nib with a label, and is subclassed from UIViewController

SecondViewController has a nib with a button, and is subclassed from BaseViewController.

SecondViewController should also have the label from the BaseViewController.

I have searched an not found any tutorials on this, only tutorials with ways to add UIView's to UIViewControllers, so I'm not sure this is even possible.

Can anyone explain how to do this, or point me in the direction to the resources that show how to do this (or if it's even possible at all)?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a hierarchy of controllers and it works just fine. As long as your correct match nibs to properties at each level, there is no reason you cannot define parent controllers in a hierarchy.

Comment: Okay, but how do I set up the nibs?  The base nib is 320 x 480, and the next nib is also the same size?  Or should it be smaller, and if so, how does it get placed?  As it is now, it's not working correctly for me and I still haven't found any good information on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you are asking can be done.  A view can be loaded from only one nib.  You could have the base view controller set up with a nib, and descendant view controllers do additional setup in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I'm thinking this is the case (so far).  I've always been able to work from one nib (usually a base view controller), then added/changed functionality, but I'm hoping there is another way as well.